# How can i return response before job is'nt done in spring

Tags: spring, rest

I would make a simple restful api in spring boot.
This api trigger a hard job that takes about 20 min.

Request is performed by another spring boot project.
And request's wanted is only to trigger, not return data.
I can't wait end of this job. So I have to separated api call and 20 minute job.

I think that async is not way...

How can i do this?
Only way is to use a message broker?

Comment: *I think that async is not way...* and why exactly?

Comment: Because way of async is just way to send pre-completed response. A request is preformed by a method in other project. I think that this method is finished after response is completed anyway... isn't it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by `async`. I general - you gonna push your job into the backgrund one way or the other.

Comment: @Antoniossss Got it... I had a big confuse. Async is a way. Thanks.